# remove everything but Number in Lex/flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

Im getting stuck with trying to remove everything but Number (Using Lex). And then using the result number in the next process.

Exp: Inputl: `abcde1!"2#$34qwesd` -> expected output: `1234`

My regex but It didnt work out:

```
DIGIT        [0-9]
%%
[^{DIGIT}-]+        {};
```

Any advise would be helpful.

#### Edit:

But when I add some more regex(es) for the next process, It worked no more. Do you know why?

Like this:

```
%% 

{NON_DIGIT}+ 

^(0{DIGIT}{1,4})[- ]({DIGIT}{1,4})[- ]({DIGIT}{4})$ { 
        printf("Well formed: [%s]\n", yytext); 
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi I've updated my answer according to your edit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal working example:

```
%%
[^0-9]+    // Just leave it blank
```

Test it: `flex test.lex && gcc lex.yy.c -lfl && ./a.out`.
For using something like an identifier, this would do:

```
NONDIGIT    [^0-9]
%%
{NONDIGIT}+    // Just leave it blank
```

#### EDITED:

In your new example I guess you want to parse `1` or `4` with expression `{1,4}` which is incorrect. Use `(1|4)` or `[14]` would do the work.
Example:

```
DIGIT       [0-9]
NON_DIGIT   [^0-9]
%%
^(0{DIGIT}(1|4))[- ]({DIGIT}[14])[- ]({DIGIT}4)$ {
        printf("Well formed: [%s]\n", yytext);
        return 0;
    }
```

Test:

```
[pengyu@GLaDOS tmp]$ flex a.lex && gcc lex.yy.c -lfl && ./a.out 
014 21 -94
014 21 -94
014 21-94
Well formed: [014 21-94]
[pengyu@GLaDOS tmp]$
```

Notice the first example I gave was rejected (not parsed) and the second was accepted.

Comment: @Kingcesc if you have any further requests, plz just edit the question instead of leaving them in comments. thx :)